# Applied Strokes using iText .NET are displaced for some PDFs

Tags: c#, pdf, annotations, itext

Modified coordinates based on the Page size working with some PDFs but not working with few PDFs

```
for (int j = 1; j < path.Length; j++)
{
    object[] cpoint = (object[])path[j];
    float x = float.Parse(cpoint[1].ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
    float y = float.Parse(cpoint[2].ToString(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
    x = getXYOfPDF(pageSize.Width, x, pdfJSWidth);
    y = getXYOfPDF(pageSize.Height, y, pdfJShight);
    y = pageSize.Height - y;
    appearance.LineTo(x, y);

}
```

Comment: What is the question? What are the example data to reproduce the issue with?

Comment: I've applied strokes on PDF page using coordinate values with iTextsharp. But, the issue is: The stroke with same coordinates placed at different places for different PDFs

Comment: As each PDF page can have its own coordinate system, drawing something at the same *x,y* coordinate values on different pages may result in it being in the middle of one page, at the edge of the next, and off-screen on yet another. Furthermore, you use the variable name `appearance`. That sounds like you're drawing not in the page content but in the appearance stream of some annotation each of which may have yet another coordinate system. But as your code snipplet contains so many unknowns, it's hard to tell where you actually are drawing and whether you're taking the differences into account.